# Universal property of tensor product of dg algebras

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, universal-property

Does the tensor product of dg algebras have a universal property? I have not seen anything about this in the literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C$ is any symmetric monoidal category, then the tensor product of commutative algebras in $C$ is their coproduct. The tensor product of algebras in $C$, not necessarily commutative, is the "commutative coproduct": We have to add to the universal property that the test morphisms commute with each other. Now apply this to $C=$ chain complexes.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Sorry it took me so long to accept.